# NSTimer as a timeout mechanism

Tags: iphone, cocoa, multithreading, nstimer

I'm pretty sure this is really simple, and I'm just missing something obvious. I have an app that needs to download data from a web service for display in a UITableView, and I want to display a UIAlertView if the operation takes more than X seconds to complete. So this is what I've got (simplified for brevity):

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
        <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSTimer *timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20
          target:self
        selector:@selector(initializationTimedOut:)
        userInfo:nil
         repeats:NO];

    [self doSomethingThatTakesALongTime];
    [timer invalidate];
}

- (void)doSomethingThatTakesALongTime {
    sleep(30); // for testing only
    // web service calls etc. go here
}

- (void)initializationTimedOut:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    // show the alert view
}
```

My problem is that I'm expecting the `[self doSomethingThatTakesALongTime]` call to block while the timer keeps counting, and I'm thinking that if it finishes before the timer is done counting down, it will return control of the thread to `viewDidLoad` where `[timer invalidate]` will proceed to cancel the timer. Obviously my understanding of how timers/threads work is flawed here because the way the code is written, the timer never goes off. However, if I remove the `[timer invalidate]`, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a problem with scheduling a timer and doing a blocking call on the same thread. Until the blocking call is completed, the run-loop cannot fire the timer.

I suggest you to detach a thread to perform the long operation. Once the long operation is finished, call back on the main thread to invalidate the timer.

Note: it is important to invalidate the timer on the same thread it was scheduled.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20
          target:self
        selector:@selector(initializationTimedOut:)
        userInfo:nil
         repeats:NO];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doSomethingThatTakesALongTime:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)doSomethingThatTakesALongTime:(id)arg {
    sleep(30); // for testing only
    // web service calls etc. go here
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invalidate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)invalidate {
    [timer invalidate];
}

- (void)initializationTimedOut:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    // show the alert view
}
```

Comment: This works very well. The only additional thing I had to do was initialize an NSAutoreleasePool inside doSomethingThatTakesALongTime. Thanks!

Comment: side note: when invalidating the timer it is usually good to both check that the timer is not nil before invalidating it and setting the timer to nil after.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `[NSThread sleepforTimeInterval:30];` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep()` occurs on the main thread and the associated run loop never has the chance to invoke the selector for the timer.

If you would do real work in `-doSomething` that doesn't block the thread, e.g. non-blocking calls to web-services, it would work as expected. Blocking calls however would have to be done in a different thread so the main run loop does not get blocked.